# Как достать идентификатор картинки из базы данных?

Tags: java, android, sql

Всем известно, что у каждой картинки используемой в коде есть свой `id`. И чтобы получить его достаточно набрать `R.drawable.имя_картинки`. Но есть один нюанс: как получить `id` если этой картинки нет в компьютере, а находится она, например, в базе банных?

Comment: Никак, ссылки на ресурсы возможны только для , собственно, ресурсов - содержимого папки /res

Comment: В каком виде хранятся ваши картинки в БД? какие то ссылки, имена файлов или сами изображения.

Comment: В виде ссылок на их адреса в интернете

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы получаете по `R.drawable.имя_картинки` фактически не `ID`, а ссылка - путь до файла в внутреннем каталоге ресурсов приложения, в вашем случае - содержимого папки `/res/drawable/`. Обратиться таким образом можно только к содержимому внутренних ресурсов вашей программы - тому, что находится в папке `res/`.

Для того, чтобы обратиться к данным, хранящимся в БД, вам нужно считать их оттуда в специализированный объект `Cursor` и затем уже работать с данными, извлекая их из полученного курсора с помощью методов класса `Cursor`.
Для реализации `ID` вам следует завести для этого специальную колонку в БД с именем `_id` и ключом `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` и извлекать эту колонку при выборке в курсор вместе с другими данными.
Так же вы можете завести в БД отдельную колонку с "именами" записей и делать выборку из БД по этому имени, получая затем другие данные (из других колонок) найденной записи.

Для лучшего понимания работы с БД прочитайте [этот](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html) (и последующие) урок.